# $n$ is a prime number $\iff $ $\frac{Tn(x)}{x}$ is irreducible on $Q[x]$

Tags: polynomials, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials, chebyshev-polynomials

Let $n$ be an odd number. Prove that $n$ is a prime number $ \iff$ $\frac{T_n(x)}{x}$ is irreducible on $Q[x]$
We have that  $ $ $T_n(x)$ is Chebyshev polynominal
please help me :((

Comment: A Google search found [this paper](http://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/doug/otherpapers/ICM-199802-0001.pdf).

Comment: thanks for your help, it's helped me so much